# Trouble training Gensim word2vec on NLTK Brown Corpus

Tags: python, nltk, gensim, word2vec

I am trying to train `Gensim` library's `word2vec` on `NLTK` `Brown Corpus`, But facing issues while setting the path to the corpus

**Code**

```
from gensim.models import word2vec

sentences = word2vec.BrownCorpus('/nltk_data/corpora/brown')

model = word2vec.Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=1)
```

**Error**

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/nltk_data/corpora/brown'

I have checked, Brown corpus data is present at the above path.

I know there is one another way to train Gensim word2vec on NLTK Brown Corpus as follows, But I want to know why the above method doesn't work

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from nltk.corpus import brown

sentences = brown.sents()

model = Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=1)
```

Feel free to drop any thoughts

Comment: Can you show your directory's `ls`? `/nltk_data/corpora/brown` mean you start from the very root directory, it is different from `nltk_data/corpora/brown` (without beginning slash), which find `nltk_data` in your current directory

Comment: @enamoria my code is present in `/Desktop/NLP` and `nltk_data` directory is present in `home`

Comment: So just replace `/nltk_data/corpora/brown` with `/home/<username>/nltk_data/corpora/brown`

Comment: Please show the full error stack for your `FileNotFoundError` – is it occurring at your `BrownCorpus` instantiation, or later?